# Any way to get the faces of the bounding box

Tags: three.js

Is there any way to get the face of the bounding box as we get in geometry. As I tried the bounding box only generates the min max value.

What I can't figure out is how to get a face for the bounding box-- is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean with "phase"?

Comment: I'm sorry! @prisoner849 It's face of the bounding box

Comment: But the bounding box has no faces. It's purely mathematical object, defined with min and max vectors.

Answer (score 1):

An AABB has no concept of faces. So no, `Box3` does not provide properties/methods for face access. However, you can try to apply the translation of the AABB to a mesh with the same size and then work with the respective box geometry.

Keep in mind that a bounding box in `three.js` (an instance of `Box3`) is always axis-aligned. So you can't apply any rotation to it.

`three.js R109`

Comment: what is the difference in AABB and AABB's ? @Mugen

Comment: I've edited my text so it's easier to understand (hopefully^^). It was just a typo.